# Google Earth Engine projection

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine

[GEE's documentation on `ee.Geometry.Polygon`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-geometry-polygon) says this about the `proj` paramter

> The projection of this geometry. The default is the projection of the
> inputs, where Numbers are assumed to be EPSG:4326.

In my understanding, coordinate reference systems (CRS) can be categorized into Geographic Coordinate System (GCS) and Projected Coordinate System (PCS). EPSG:4326 belongs to the GCS category, not PCS  [[ref]](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/coordinate_reference_systems.html#coordinate-reference-system-crs-in-detail). So how can the 'projection' of a geometry be 'EPSG:4326'

More strictly speaking, aren't map projections techniques to represent a spheroid on a flat surface? How can it be a CRS at all?

Comment: "Projection" is a misnomer for GCS objects, but not heinously so. "CRS" is accurate for both projected and geographic reference systems, as is "spatial reference," though in the Esri definition of SR, CRS is only one aspect, which also includes vertical reference, tolerances, and false origin and scaling for XY, Z, and M dimensions.

Comment: Correctly formulated statement should probably be: The CRS of this geometry. The default is the CRS of the inputs, where Numbers are assumed to be EPSG:4326.

Comment: So basically combining what you guys wrote: The particular GEE doc wasn't written in a very precise manner. It should have wrote "CRS", but using "projection" is a somewhat acceptable convention. If that is the case, it is enough to answer my question, so can one of you please post your comment as the answer so I can mark it as solved?